# QtC++ QVector<QString> Ошибка

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

```
void Line::RemoveSpaces()
{
// Цикл по всем "компонентам" строки
    for (int i = 0; i < _line.size(); ++i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_line[i][0] == ' ' || _line[i][0] == '\n' || _line[i][0] == '\t')
            {
                _line[i].remove(0, 1); // Вот эта строчка
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = _line[i].length() - 1; j > 0; --j)
        {
            if (_line[i][j] == ' ' || _line[i][j] == '\n' || _line[i][j] == '\t')
            {
                _line[i].remove(j, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (_line[i] == "")
        {
            _line.erase(_line.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

`_line` - это `QVector<QString>`

До вызова функции `RemoveSpaces` - `_line` равна:

```
{"class", " jopa ", "{", " ", "int", " main", "(", "\t", ")", "\t", "{", "\n", "}", "\n\n\n\t\t  ", "}", "\n\n"}
```

Ожидаемый результат после:

```
{"class", "jopa", "{", "int", "main", "(", ")", "{", "}", "}"}
```

Ожидания оправдали надежды. Результат верный. Но в консоль выводится следующие:
`Using QCharRef with an index pointing outside the valid range of a QString. The corresponding behavior is deprecated, and will be changed in a future version of Qt.`

Причем много раз. При отладке я заметил, что первый раз выводится когда на `"Вот этой строчке(в коде есть комментарий)"` `i равна 4`. И `_line[i] равна " main"`

Что означает эта надпись и как от неё избавится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на этот код детальнее

```
 while (true)
    {
        if (_line[i][0] == ' ' || _line[i][0] == '\n' || _line[i][0] == '\t')
        {
            _line[i].remove(0, 1); // Вот эта строчка
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

и допустим в строке просто один пробел. При первом проходе этот пробел будет удален. При следующем цикле строка будет пустая, но Вы пытаетесь прочитать первый символ. А его нет... Может заменить условие на такое:

```
while (!_line[i].isEmpty())
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Правда я не понимаю почему при дебаге сообщение выводится только при удалении. Но да ладно, как говорится: главное что работает!

Comment: обращение за пределы массива - это UB, компилятор имеет право обрабатывать это на свое усмотрение. Можно ругнуться, можно проигнорировать, а можно диск форматнуть

Answer (score 2):

А лучше выбросить этот код и написать что-то такое :)

```
QStringList _line = {"class", " jopa ", "{", " ", "int", " main", "(", "\t", ")", "\t", "{", "\n", "}", "\n\n\n\t\t  ", "}", "\n\n"};
for(auto& str : _line) {
    str = str.simplified();
}
_line.removeAll(QString{});
```

Comment: О, спасибо! Я просто начинал писать код на STL, а щас решил на Qt переходить.